# Calculating with multiple dates in same cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe such as below

```
   userid   recorddate              alertdate
0    tom    2018-06-12 00:00:00.0   2018-06-13 00:00:00.0, 2015-04-13 00:00:00.0
1    nick   2019-06-01 00:00:00.0   2019-11-11 00:00:00.0, 2020-02-12 00:00:00.0, 2020-01-10 00:00:00.0
2    bob    2019-06-02 00:00:00.0   2019-06-01 00:00:00.0
```

What I am looking to do is take the dates within column "alertdate" and see whether any of them are within 10 days before recorddate.

In this example, tom would because of the 2018-06-13 value.

I know how to do this if there is only one date in alertdate, but in this column there may be many dates seperated by a column.

Any help or tips for doing this? I would be creating a new column with a simple boolean on whether there was an alertdate within 10 days of after recorddate. If possible, without creating new rows to seperate the dates because the dataframe will contain columns of other data and would like to prevent duplicates.

Thanks!

Comment: did I answer your question? If so, can you please accept as answer and upvote if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach:

1. I read in your input with a double-space delimiter.
2. I transformed the strings to lists in the `df['alertdate']` column with `split()`.
3. I created a column called `df['alertdate_lt_10days']` which first assumes 'No' and then will return 'Yes' later for the relevant rows.
4. I looped through the columns, rows and cells, with the key things being:
   a. first `for` statement - use `zip()` to loop through the rows of two columns simultaneously and b. second `for` statement - loop through lists in cells of the `alertdate` column in order to be able to compare the dates to see if they were within 10 days of each other
5. I converted the `recorddate` and `alertdate` strings to dates and then used `.days` to convert a `timedelta` object to an `integer` (subtracting dates creates a timedelta object by default, which cannot be compared against integers).
6. Finally, I used the ever-useful and practical `np.where()` to assign a 'Yes' to the new column we created earlier.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+\s+')

df['alertdate'] = df['alertdate'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df['alertdate_lt_10days'] = 'No'
for recorddate, list_alertdate in zip(df['recorddate'], df['alertdate']):
    for alertdate in list_alertdate:
        if -10 < (pd.to_datetime(alertdate) - pd.to_datetime(recorddate)).days < 10:
            df['alertdate_lt_10days'] = np.where(df['recorddate'] == recorddate, 'Yes', df['alertdate_lt_10days'])
df
```

Ouput:

```
        userid  recorddate                  alertdate             alertdate_lt_10days
0       tom     2018-06-12 00:00:00.0       [2018-06-13 00:00:00.0, 2015-04-13 00:00:00.0]  Yes
1       nick    2019-06-01 00:00:00.0       [2019-11-11 00:00:00.0, 2020-02-12 00:00:00.0...    No
2       bob     2019-06-02 00:00:00.0       [2019-06-01 00:00:00.0]            Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the 'alertdate' values into lists of dates with `str.split()`:

```py
df['alertdate'] = df['alertdate'].str.split(', ')
```

Then you can just loop over the rows and the list elements for each row to make the comparisons, using `pd.to_datetime()`.